# How to add a content language to a website using norconex 3.0.1?

Tags: locale

In version 2.9.1 I was able to add content language to site fields using this method:

```
public static @NotNull IDocumentTagger addContentLanguage(@NotNull String fieldName) {
    return (reference, document, metadata, parsed) -> {
        Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag(metadata.getString(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LANGUAGE));
        metadata.setString(fieldName, locale.getLanguage());
    };
}
```

When using version 2.9.1 in this Lambda metadata is of class `com.norconex.importer.doc.ImporterMetadata`.
In version 3.0.1 IntelliJ tells me that metadata is of class `com.norconex.importer.parser.ParseState` which is an *enum* with solely the elements `PRE` and `POST` and methods `isPre()` and `isPost()`.
Furthermore, Maven complains: *incompatible types: incompatible parameter types in lambda expression*.

How can I achieve the result of the given method in version 3.0.1?